# Business Connectivity Service on Sharepoint online-How to link with external data source?

Tags: sharepoint-online, bcs, database, external-data

We have a sharepoint online(O365) solution,now we are maintaining all our dept user data in a virtual db in our dept itself,i just want to know how to connect our sharepoint site to that data source and to fetch,create or update data from and to our db ?

Comment: Where is the DB Hosted?

Comment: Actually,all the department datas are stored in a local machine inside the dept itself as a virtual DB and whole organization datas are stored in Data Centers,which may be required for authenticating organization users(while doing some information gathering activity or something like that)